# Will a custom RoleProvider work with [Authorize] on action method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

I'm making a custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider.

I have database tables with Roles and UsersInRoles and I use LINQ-to-SQL to create objects of the tables.

When invoking [Authorize] on an action method, will it work with my custom RoleProvider?
How does it know if the user is authenticated and if the user is in the appropriate role?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The *AuthorizeAttribute* uses *User.IsUserInRole()* method internally. But you have to set your custom provider as default.

**Scenario**

When the role management is enabled, the *RoleManagerModule* replaces the *HttpContext.User* value with a new instance of *RolePrincipal*. The *RolePrincipal* uses *Roles.IsUserInRole* internally as well.